# Meteor Collections using find selector to discriminate against certain variable

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I understand we can use find with the selector to get specific elements in a collection like so:

```
usernames.find(selector)
```

To specify finding all usernames with a specific property like "Bob" as the name I would do:

```
usernames.find({name: "Bob"})
```

Which would only show me documents that have the name Bob. But let's say there are other people in my collection like Alice and Kat and I want to find everyone in the collection whose name is not Bob.

**How would I specify a selector to find everything in the usernames collection whose name is not Bob?**

I've tried:

```
usernames.find({name: !"Bob"})
```

I'm stuck on the syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $ne operator

`usernames.find( { name: { $ne: "Bob" } })`

$ne selects the documents where the value of the field is not equal to the specified value. This includes documents that do not contain the field.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/